# Live agent custom detail fields reordering

Tags: liveagent

I have a requirement of rearranging the fields in custom details box. When I hover over the chat accept form, it displays the values, which I have entered in the pre chat form. But the order its displayed is not similar to the order  I have entered the values. Is there any way, I can rearrange the display fields order?
I would be really grateful if there is any help/suggestion

regards,
PH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a similar requirement myself, based on my interaction with Salesforce.com Support at the current time there is no way to rearrange the fields on the Visitor 'ChatLet' section on the Live agent console and also when the chat invitation is shown.

The arrangement of the visitor entered information on the Pre-chat window is dynamically populated by Salesforce on chatlet and chat invitation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You are right. I tried a lot.But in vain